# How to specify a generic Type parameter in XSD Data Contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, datacontracts, wscf

I have the following Request and Response Data Contract pair for a Webservice method call

```
  <xs:element name="GetUserOptionsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OptionType" type="entities:UserOption" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="GetUserOptionsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Options" type="entities:UserOption" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The problem is that what I want to have is a way of saying (pseudocode)

```
GetUserResponse response = GetuserOptions(new GetUserOptionsRequest(Type T))
```

And to have the response contain an IList depending on what type I pass through.

With my above data contract XSD, it is expecting an instance of a class in the request object, when I just want to specify a Type definition.

Really I suppose what I would want it

```
GetUserResponse<T> response = GetUserOptions(new GetUserOptionsRequest<T>());
```

But Im not sure how to specify generic classes/methods in XSD. Can anyone point me at a good article or explain how I can define this in XSD?

I am using WSCF blue for code generation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's **not possible** to define types with *open generics* in XSD.

Actually, XSD doesn't have a native way of representing generic type arguments at all. However, if you are going to generate *.NET types* out of the XSD schema, you can [mimic *closed* generic arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/gg413252#O) by decorating a type with an [`<xsd:annotation>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256102.aspx) containing an [`<xsd:appinfo>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256134.aspx) element:

```
<xs:element name="Foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <GenericType Name="FooOf{0}{#}"
                             Namespace="...">
                    <GenericParameter Name="string"
                                      Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
                </GenericType>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

This XSD schema will be represented in the .NET type system as a class of type `Foo<string>`. Note that in this example the generic argument is specified as `string`, but nothing prevents you from *reusing* the same XSD element definition in multiple contracts with different generic arguments.

Also, note that the `GenericType` element is *not* part of the XSD standard and will only be interpreted by a .NET code generation tool.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just as an aside, is it possible to specify in XSD that your class is a sub-class of another base type? Eg if I have a UserChoice object defined with an Id and Description field, can I then declare in XSD types such as TravelChoice, SportChoice, FamilyChoice which all inherit from UserChoice and don't add any more behaviour than what the base object has?

Comment: @user1122909 **Yes**, you can express inheritance with the `<xsd:extension base="MyBaseType" />` element. Check out this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1939062/26396