# Converting XSD to C# classes using an extension schema. Problems with root element in the class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have used a program (xsd2code++) to generate C# code from an XSD file. The XSD file I converted is an extension schema to the LandXML schema.

The autogenerated code and XSD show the root element as HexagonLandXML, whereas the XML sample file has the root code as LandXML. This causes an error when I deserialize the XML as the XmlRootAttribute namespace is unexpected.

Wondering what the best way to fix the classes would be? Is there a simple way to edit the classes to add the correct root element?

Extract from top of sample XML file. **Root element is LandXML**. HexagonLandXML is a sub-element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2022-06-11" time="18:33:56.0715486+10:00" version="1.2" language="English">
  <Units>
    <Metric areaUnit="squareMeter" linearUnit="meter" volumeUnit="cubicMeter" temperatureUnit="celsius" pressureUnit="milliBars" diameterUnit="meter" widthUnit="meter" heightUnit="meter" angularUnit="grads" directionUnit="grads" latLongAngularUnit="decimal dd.mm.ss" />
  </Units>
  <Application name="Infinity" manufacturer="Leica Geosystems" version="3.1" manufacturerURL="http://www.leica-geosystems.com" timeStamp="2022-06-11T18:33:56.0715486+10:00">
    <Author createdBy="Infinity 3.1 - LandXml 1" company="Leica Geosystems" companyURL="http://www.leica-geosystems.com" timeStamp="2022-06-11T18:33:56.0715486+10:00" />
  </Application>
  <HexagonLandXML xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9">
    <Codelist codelistName="MLS_v14" codelistDescription="MLS v14 Codelist" codelistCreator="SM" dateCreated="2022-05-11T14:13:13.729705+10:00">
      <CodeGroup codeGroupName="Roads" activatedOnInstrument="true">
        <Code codeName="KERB" codeDesc="Kerbs" codeType="Point">
```

Extract top of XSD file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:hexagon="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9" xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" targetNamespace="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="HexagonLandXML">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Extensions to the LandXML schema</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
```

Autogenerated classes extract with **[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9", IsNullable=false)]**:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9")]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class HexagonLandXML
{
```

There are many classes created that all have the following:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.9")]
```

Comment: Any chance you could share a [mcve]?  See [ask].

Comment: In order for `xsd.exe` to generate a type hierarchy, the definition for the derived type must declare that it extends the base type via an [`<xs:extension`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-typeExtension) element. See e.g. [XML Schema extension Element](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_extension.asp), [`<xsd:extension>` Element (complexContent)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256161(v=vs.100)) and [What's the meaning of "xsd:extension base = ....?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1939062).

Comment: But I don't see any `<xs:extension` in your schema.  Absent that you're not going to get a type hierarchy.  Maybe the schema is using containment instead of inheritance?  We need to see a [mcve] to be sure, but *probably* the schema doesn't say what you think it does.

Comment: the schema URL is wrong in the xml.  It should be the following webpage : http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd.  You may be using the wrong xml schema version.  I would take the schema from webpage and try creating the classes  again.  Also try modifying the URL in the xml.  It may be that the people who generated the xml file never checked the file against the schema.  You may need to contact the people who generated the xml and have them fix the schema errors.